# Anychart Android how to add listener to "renderfinish" with stage.listen or stage.listenOnce

Tags: java, android, android-studio, anychart

I have seen Anychart library has some embedded listeners included. I would be interested to use the "renderfinish" (https://docs.anychart.com/Graphics/Events) method from this library within the Java environment of an Android app.

So far, I haven't managed to achieve it. Any ideas in how to achieve it?

The idea behind would be to launch a function once the graphic has been first rendered to the user.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Android version of the library doesn't support 100% of the JS library features. The mentioned list of events is not supported now.

Comment: Oh, well, thank you very much! It will be nice if it were possible in the future, if not, thank you anyway for your fast reply and for all the support! :D